# TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python

Только начал изучать Python (да и вообще программирование). Нужна программа для вывода данных из базы по номеру телефона.Без проверки наличия номера в базе работает. Но хочу с начала проверить на наличии такой записи в базе и только потом выполнить вывод.

```
print("Input number in format 0YYYxxxx:")
x = input()
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect ("D:\DB_SQLITE\elta_db.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute ("""select Raion, bloc, realphone, phone, elta_number.coord, elta_coord.coord, elta_coord.board,
                    elta_coord.port_on_board
              from elta_number INNER JOIN elta_coord ON elta_number.coord = elta_coord.coord where realphone=?""", (x,))
for row in cursor:
    if (x,)== row(2):
        print ("Number= ", row[3])
        print ("District= ", row[0])
        print ("Bloc=  ", row[1])
        print ("Coord= " , row[4])
        print ("Board= ",row[6])
        print ("Port=  ",row[7])
    else:
        print ("This number don't exist")
conn.close
```

Результат:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:/programing/Elta_numar__for_forum.py", line 10, in <module>
>     if (x,)== row(2):
> TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
> ```

Comment: Что ожидается от ``row(2)``? Не должно ли там быть ``row[2]``?

Comment: Думаю, должно быть что-то такое `if x == row[2] ...`

Comment: вы правы - должны быть квадратные скобки.Ошибка исчезла, но в результате все наоборот. Когда ввожу номер существующий в базе - ответ - "This number don't exist". Когда ввожу несуществующий номер - ничего.

Answer (score 2):

Вместо

```
cursor.execute ("""select Raion, bloc, realphone, phone, elta_number.coord, elta_coord.coord, elta_coord.board,
                elta_coord.port_on_board
          from elta_number INNER JOIN elta_coord ON elta_number.coord = elta_coord.coord where realphone=?""", (x,))
```

напишите

```
cursor.execute ("""select Raion, bloc, realphone, phone, elta_number.coord, elta_coord.coord, elta_coord.board,
                elta_coord.port_on_board
          from elta_number INNER JOIN elta_coord ON elta_number.coord = elta_coord.coord""")
```

и вместо

```
if (x,)== row(2):
```

напишите

```
if x == row[2]:
```

Comment: if x == row[2]: Не помогло. Если убрать(x,))из запроса SQL -то вообще ошибка. Ощущение то проверяется тип данных вводимых и тех что в базе.

Comment: Я слишком изменил мой ответ. Попробуйте, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Задача решена.

```
print("Input number in format YYYxxxx:")
x = input()
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect ("Elta_DB.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute ("""select Raion, bloc, realphone, phone, elta_number.coord, elta_coord.coord, elta_coord.board,
                    elta_coord.port_on_board
              from elta_number INNER JOIN elta_coord ON elta_number.coord = elta_coord.coord where realphone=?""",(x,))
data=cursor.fetchall()    #если номер существует, то что-то получим, если нет, то пустой список
if len(data):
    for row in data:
#        if int(x) == int(row[2]):   #это не нужно, если мы здесь, то есть нужные данные
        print ("Number= ", row[2])
        print ("District= ", row[0])
        print ("Bloc=  ", row[1])
        print ("Coord= " , row[4])
        print ("Board= ",row[6])
        print ("Port=  ",row[7])
else:
    print ("This number don't exist")
conn.close
```